# How should I set up a user creation form that allows managers to create accounts for employees?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

So I have extended my user model with a OneToOneField. My goal is to allow a Manager type user the ability to create employee users.

One of the main issues I'm running into is populating the brewery foreign key field. For some reason anytime I submit the form with a brewery selected I get a "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'brewery_id'" even though a brewery_id had been chosen. A user however is still created just not the extended customer part.

Ideally I would like the brewery_id to populate for the new user based off the manager who is creating that user.

I know my problem lies somewhere in my view but all the examples I can find of this are just for updating the current user.

models.py :

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    brewery = models.ForeignKey(Brewery, models.DO_NOTHING)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    phone_carrier = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    class Meta:
        managed = True

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Customer.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.customer.save()
```

forms.py :

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('brewery', 'phone_number', 'phone_carrier', 'role')
```

views.py:

```
@login_required
def adminsite_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        cust_form = CustomerForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid() and cust_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            cust_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Account has been created! You can now log in.')
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            messages.error(request, f'Please correct the errors.')
    else:
        user_form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        cust_form = CustomerForm(request.POST)
    return render(request, "AdminSite/adminControls.html", {'user_form': user_form, 'cust_form': cust_form})
```

Comment: in your customer model,the brewery field ,you should be doing : on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING..and in the signal you arent creationg the customer object with brewery  Customer.objects.create(user=instance,brewery=?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is this line in your signal receiver:

```
if created:
    Customer.objects.create(user=instance)
```

This is trying to create a `Customer` without specifying a `Brewery` and will trigger the error.

It seems as though your reason for using the signal receivers is to associate a `User` with a `Customer`. It may be easier to do this association in the view such as this:

```
@login_required
def adminsite_register(request):
    ...
    if user_form.is_valid() and cust_form.is_valid():
        user = user_form.save()
        customer = cust_form.save(commit=False)  # Don't commit the customer just yet
        customer.user = user  # Associate the user
        customer.save()  # Now save the customer
        ...
```

and then delete the signal receivers entirely.